# Mutual exclusion (in static library )

Tags: c++, windows, informix

I have a **static library** to access a Database. It has a function `readMaximum()`.

readMaximum() reads a maximum value from DB. This function is thread safe (using mutex).

**But problem is :**

There are two processes **A.exe** and **B.exe**; both are compiled with the **static library**.

Is there any way where I can implement mutual exclusion between process A.exe and B.exe, so that when function `readMaximum()` is called by two processes at same time, only one is allow to go into the critical section?

PS. I would not like to change any property of the DB/Schema/Table.

Comment: Managing concurrency like this should be a function of the database. What database are you using, and why do you need mutual exclusion for two reads? Does anything else happen in the function?

Comment: its IBM Informix,It seems informix behaviour is not correct (may be some bug). we are inserting current time  stamp in table and getting max row count for that

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'getting max row count'?  Which version of IDS?  Which API are you using?  Are you going to update the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreateMutex() to created a named global mutex. Prefix the name with "Global\".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [named semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a.aspx).  It is visible to all processes and can control that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX has mutexes which can be shared among the processes.